# HttpURLConnection does not respond nor throw an exception

Tags: java, http, exception, xmlhttprequest, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send a `HTTP request` for a collection of URLs for accessing the content of corresponding pages. But somehow, for few URLs, the `HttpURLConnection` does not do anything and the program stays Idle. 
Here is my code:

```
                        while(null != (line = br.readLine())){
                        URL url = new URL(line);
                        openConnection(url);
                            }

             static void openConnection(URL url) {

                       URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                          if (connection instanceof HttpURLConnection) {
                        try{
                              httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;

                              httpConn.setConnectTimeout(2000);


                         int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                         if (statusCode <= 200 && statusCode < 300)
                         {
                         //do something

                           }

                          }
                               catch (ConnectException|java.lang.IllegalArgumentException ex) { java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateXMLtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}  //catch the possible exception.
                               catch (SSLHandshakeException |SocketException | SocketTimeoutException | UnknownHostException ex) {java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateXMLtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
                               catch (java.io.IOException ex) { java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CreateXMLtest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);} 

               }

          }
```

For some reasons, the program gets idle at line ` int statusCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();. How to prevent, or at least, skip this case?

Comment: Does it move to the next line after time out  ?

Comment: @bluelurker Of course not, then how else it would be idle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a timeout:

```
 httpConn.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);  //milliseconds
 httpConn.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
```

and then catch java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

> If the timeout expires before the connection can be established, a
>   java.net.SocketTimeoutException is raised. A timeout of zero is
>   interpreted as an infinite timeout.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify socket read timeout (SO timeout) . Defualt is infinity. So thread will read indefinitely(theorotically) if not specified.

Comment: I looked at your code. You have set connectiontimeout not read timeout. Think before voting down